# shutil.move() file disappeared

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

so I created a basic shutil.move() patch to move files on my desktop. Problem is, I specified a destination for the file to go to that is nonexistent (in this case, "Docs"), and now I can't find my file. My question is, simply, where did my file go given this Docs command is nonexistent?

```
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(('.docx', '.doc')):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), "Docs")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Where is root located? What is the path for root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In actual fact, further to my comment (I just tested your code), what you have actually done here is taken your file or files (f) once after the other and moved them to a file called "Docs".  I haven't tested with multi files, but if you had many, I'd say, with each file, you have clobbered (overwritten) the one before ending up with just a single file named "Docs" in the root directory.
If what I understand you are trying to do is correct, you want to move your files from the current location, perhaps into another directory inside root.
The code for that would be.

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "Docs", f))
```

This also assumes that "Docs" exists.  If it doesn't then your code will error out.
A line before doing something like:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(root, "Docs")):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "Docs"))
```

Final code from me that I used (assuming this is what you want to achieve):

```
import shutil
import os

root =('.') # for the sake of testing, I just used the base directory
files = os.listdir('.') # I also pulled filed from this directory for the sake of testing - I actually tested with a csv file, but the idea remains the same

for f in files:
    if f.endswith((docx', '.doc')):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(root, "Docs")):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "Docs"))
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "Docs", f))
        print(f)

    else:
        continue
```